# Telerik RadGridView items with changed properties only

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik, radgridview

I have a list of items which is displayed using RadGridView. I want to be able to get only the items from the list which have had their properties changed.

Currently, I'm using `GridName.Items` to retrieve all the items from the list. Is there a way to filter out the items in the list which haven't had their values changed?

Comment: WinForms? There are events to handle changes right after they are commited to the gridview I think: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-insert-update-delete-records-tracking-changes-in-radgridview.html

Comment: @Jannik It's a silverlight application. I used RowEditEnded event to capture the items which have been edited and only update those items in the database.